# Прочитать текстовый файл

Tags: c

Необходимо прочитать произвольный текстовый файл
Компилятор: GCC

Comment: >Необходимо прочитать произвольный текстовый файл

Читайте

Comment: Неизвестно никакой информации о содержимом файла, кроме его имени. Необходимо получить его содержимое.

Comment: Что сами сделали? Что конкретно неясно?

Comment: Что значит прочитать?

Обрабатывать хотите побайтно, построчно? Можно хоть весь сразу прочесть в память.

Comment: А кто минусанул вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int fl=open("e.c", O_RDONLY, S_IREAD);

    unsigned char buf[1025];
    int rd=read(fl, buf, 1024);
    printf("Read: %d bytes.\r\n", rd);
    buf[rd]=0;
    printf("Data: %s.\r\n", buf);

    close(fl);

    return 0;
}
```

Сохранить в файл с расширением .c . 
Собирать: gcc e.c

UPD. Добавлен вывод содержимого у файла размером не больше 1024 байта. Для более большего размера нужно добавить чтение в цикле.

Comment: Не понял. А зачем Си код собирать gcc и линковать с stdc++, а не сразу собирать g++?
Ну, по-другому - где здесь с++? Почему нельзя просто интерпретировать это как Си код?

Comment: 1. Зачем открывать на чтение-запись? Вполне достаточно O_RDONLY

2.  

> printf("Readed: %d bytes.\r\n", rd);

Не readed, а read, поелику глагол неправильный.
3. Задание невыполнено, т.к. надо прочитать все-таки произвольный файл.

Comment: @gecube, я сделал как требовалось в задаче. Оно не захотело собираться, поискал в гугле, там написано нужно stdc++. Так, понял ошибку, стоило назвать файл e.c . Из-за расширения cpp компилятор ругался на отсутствие stdc++.

@mikillskegg, да достаточно O_RDONLY, по ошибке написал O_RDWR. Что есть произвольный файл? По ощущениям это нечто из фантастики, например программа сама должна выбрать произвольный файл и прочитать его. Я так понял, что достаточно моего решения, когда произвольный файл указывается в open(). Про ввод имени файла из консоли ничего не говорилось.

Comment: Я говорил про произвольный размер файла, есно, что и требуется в задаче

Comment: @mikelsv, мозг включать полезно.

> Оно не захотело собираться, поискал в гугле, там написано нужно stdc++.
Ну, и по-Вашему, это годится под ответ с тэгом "Си"? Могу напомнить Вам еще про ключ `-std=`...

> Я так понял, что достаточно моего решения, когда произвольный файл указывается в open(). 

гипотетически автор вопроса может сам доработать Вашу программу, но лучше сделать ввод имени файла или через argc/argv (аргументы командной строки), или через ручной ввод с консоли (напр., `scanf`'ом). Ну, и не обязательно пользоваться `open`. Честно говоря, я по жизни пользовался `fopen` - я лох? =)

Comment: Буквы кончились. Продолжу здесь.

> По ощущениям это нечто из фантастики, например программа сама должна выбрать произвольный файл и прочитать его.

Ну, вообще не проблема в цикле вывести по байтику все содержимое файла. Я лично так понимаю задачу. Другой вопрос, что это не очень эффективно и выгоднее делать буферизованное чтение. Скажем, блоками по 1024 байта и тогда случается ситуация, когда файл не кратен этому блоку и хвостик нужно выводить отдельно. Ну, или еще два варианта - считать весь файл единократно в память (на больших файлах могут быть проблемы с выделением памяти)

Comment: или спроецировать память в файл. Но вот последнее не знаю умеет ли стандартная библиотека Си. Но пример было бы посмотреть интересно.

Мне, честно говоря, было бы интересно посмотреть на все способы и обсудить плюсы и недостатки каждого. По крайней мере, это позволило бы мне узнать чо-нить новое.

Comment: @gecube, спроецировать файл  в память естественно Си умеет. 

Это делается системным вызовом mmap, в libc есть интерфейс к нему. В любом случае есть там есть функция syscall, позволяющая ручками сделать любой системный вызов.

По поводу open/fopen. В данном случае IMHO fopen лучше. Не надо самому возится с буферизацией.

Comment: Мозг выключен. У него похоже выходной. Иначе б я давно задавал новые вопросы.

Чем вы пользуетесь - дело ваше. Мне больше нравятся идентификаторы в open(), с ними легче работать и передавать по сети. fopen() мне откровенно не нравится. Чем именно сформулировать не смогу. Хм, буферизация говорите, даже не знаю, когда бы она мне потребовалась.

Comment: @mikelsv, буферизация почти всегда нужна, если читаете/пишете  байтами, "словами", строчками, небольшими блоками и т.п. 

fopen() Вам не нравится видимо потому, что Вы просто stdio плохо знаете. Почитайте stdio.h, libio.h

Comment: @avp А что значит буферизация? (И как в современной ОС считать данные, минуя всякие внутренние буфера?)

Как мне кажется, все эти рассуждения про эффективность относятся ко временам, когда компьютеры были большими, а объём памяти у них -- маленьким.

Comment: @alexlz, имеется в виду буферизация в пользовательском адресном пространстве процесса.

Обращение к ядру операция весьма недешевая.

Comment: Ну я не думаю, что сектора диска (прошедшие кеширование в системе, а до того -- кеширование в контроллере) считываются в адресное пространство системы. Наверняка в пользовательское. Просто в 60е (у нас -- в 70е) если в программе на PL/I было написано buffered, значит в программе выделялся буфер, куда считывалость с устройства (диски/ленты -- DMA), а уже оттуда -- в заданные в программе переменные. unbuffered -- только в сам буфер, а программа уже оттуда читала/писала (вроде так). Цепочка была очень короткой. Сейчас -- ух, длинная, и хвосты там искать...

Comment: @alexlz, в \*nix-ах сектора диска кэшируются в памяти ядра. 

А каким еще образом можно обеспечить одновременное изменение данных файла видимое разными процессами?

Comment: @avp Ну значит наврал. Кэши-то и в других системах не в пользовательских адресах. Только сейчас я уже запутался, о чём речь шла. То, что getc по байту читает не из системного кэша -- все согласны. А дальше (для того же fget -- думаю тоже). Запутался. От дискуссии убегаю.

Answer (score 1):

@alexlz, а Вы сравните быстродействие кода с побайтным чтением и выводом и с оптимизированным кодом, который читает блоками и выводит блоками. Правда, второй код получается сложнее. Соглашусь с тем, что это получается в некотором роде premature optimization, но что поделать, если языковые средства и ОС не могут понять как сделать эффективнее...

Comment: @gecube, вот только с **premature optimization** в этом контексте, я **абсолютно не согласен**.

IMHO буферизацию здесь надо сравнивать с переходом улицы не глядя на светофор.

Comment: @avp, а завтра этот код мы начинаем использовать на какой-нибудь встроенной системе с NAND с совершенно другим размером сектора и другой схемой буферизации ФС и ловим очередные тормоза из-за неоптимального размера блока.

Comment: @gecube, Вы серьезно относитесь к переносимости без изучения-модификации-настройки? 

Я, только на уровне прототипа системы. Кстати, если уж говорить о буферизации в контексте всего обсуждения вопроса, то я за **fopen**.

Ну, а особенности внешней памяти в большей степени прерогатива драйвера.

Comment: @avp,

> Вы серьезно относитесь к переносимости без изучения-модификации-настройки?

практика говорит, что без изучения-модификации-настройки не обойтись. И это пичалька. Явно пора учить функциональные языки... Там вроде такого головняка нет

> Ну, а особенности внешней памяти в большей степени прерогатива драйвера.

Согласен. Так должно быть.

Comment: @gecube, очевидно же, я говорил о переносимости С/С++ (причем "близких к системе") программ.

К прологу, лиспу, хаскелю и прочим awk это не относится. Там все ОК (кроме *действительно больших* или *быстрых* программ).

Comment: @gecube Функциональные языки? Они к этой проблеме сугубо перпендикулярны

@avp "Там все ОК (кроме действительно больших или быстрых программ)" -- Откуда информация? Ссылочкой не поделитесь?

Comment: @alexlz, ссылочек нет, только интуиция.

Comment: @avp Так Yahoo Store из-за скорости с лиспа на C++ переписали? О как! А разработчики-то и не знают! (д.б. пиво пили). А программа для поиска маршрута авиаперелётов с пересадками, которую Грэм упоминал, почему она конкурентам по скорости не уступила?

Comment: Лисп можно бустировать. Можно своим компилятором его проблемы решить. А кресты судя по всему годятся только для написания компиляторов и dsl.